# WebBrowser Control Delete or Hide Element by Id

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, controls, webbrowser-control

I made and auto login application for support user for some wireless routers equipment all works fine but I want hide some options I get all elements Id's but don't know how to hide or disable this elements.

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").InnerText = "suport"
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").InnerText = "0123432"
    WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")

    'Dim doc1 = WebBrowser1.Document
    If e.Url.ToString() = "http://" + lbBrowserIP.Text + ":8900/link.cgi" Then
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("_wpa_key_t") "I want to disable or hide this Element"

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the element do the following:

```
Dim ele = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("_wpa_key_t") ;

If ele IsNot Nothing Then
                    ele.Style = "Display:none"
                End If
```

I hope that support you question.

Comment: Did't work but seems dome detail missing because the element it's that      ` <td class="f-left" colspan="3"><input style="display: none;" autocomplete="off" class="config pwd i_wpapsk" id="_wpa_key_x" name="_wpa_key_x" value="" type="text"><input class="config pwd   i_wpapsk" name="wpa_key" id="wpa_key" value="0123321" req="1"   callback="validateWpaKey" realname="WPA passphrase (minimum 8   printable ASCII chars, maximum 63)" autocomplete="off"   type="password"><input id="_wpa_key_t" type="checkbox"><label   for="_wpa_key_t">Show</label></td> `